# Delete specific characters from main page URL

Tags: http, url

I created a multinational page using the polylang plugin. However, when you visit the English main page, /main/ is added at the end of the URL. Is there a way to delete it?

existing url: https://pumster.com/en/main/
change url: https://pumster.com/en/

```
const baseUrl = 'https://pumster.com/cn/chnmain/';
const newUrl = baseUrl.split('/').slice(0, -1).join('/');
```

I tried this, but nothing changed.